# Find the longest/smallest consecutive sequence of a value

Tags: excel

I have a series of two values (Win/Lost) in a column and want a formula which will return the longest and the smallest consecutive sequences of each value.

For example, if values in Column A are:

```
Win, Lost, Lost, Win, Win, Lost, Lost, Lost, Win, Lost, Lost, Lost, Lost, Lost, Win, Win, Win
```

then the results (somewhere in Column B) should be:

Longest Win Sequence=3
Smallest Win Sequence=1
Longest Lost Sequence=5
Smallest Lost Sequence=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you OK with using a few extra columns (which you can hide, or place further to the right)?  If so -- then insert a blank row 1.  Then use this formula starting in B2, and drag down:

```
=if(and($A1="Win",$A2="Win"),B1+1,"")
```

and this formula starting in C2, and drag down:

```
=if(and($A1="Lost",$A2="Lost"),B1+1,"")
```

and then

in D2: `="Longest Win Sequence=" & max(B:B)`

in D3: `="Shortest Win Sequence=" & min(B:B)`

in D4: `="Longest Lost Sequence=" & max(C:C)`

in D5: `="Shortest Lost Sequence=" & min(C:C)`

Comment: It is tricky but it worked! Thanks ExactaBox!

Comment: It didn't work for me, but it was close. The sequence count was off by 1. Here is how I got it to work: =IF(AND($C3=0,$C4=0),D2+1, IF(AND($C2=0, $C3=0), D2+1, 0))